# I have written code for my project in VHDL, but im getting an error while using signal

Tags: vhdl, fpga

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
entity keygeneration is
    Port ( key : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (127 downto 0);
           rc : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           keyout : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (127 downto 0));
end keygeneration;

architecture Behavioral of keygeneration is

component sbox is
     port(a: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
          y: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
end component;
component RCON is
 Port ( rc : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
            rout : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0));
end component;
signal w0,w1,w2,w3,tem: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
signal rout1: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);

begin
-- 52nd line below
w0<=key[127 downto 96];
w1<=key[95 downto 64];
w2<=key[63 downto 32];
w3<=key[31 downto 0];

t1: sbox port map(w3[23 downto 16],tem[31 downto 0]);
t2: sbox port map(w3[15 downto 8],tem[23 downto 16]);
t3: sbox port map(w3[7 downto 0],tem[15 downto 8]);
t4: sbox port map(w3[31 downto 24],tem[7 downto 0]);

r1: RCON port map(rc[3 downto 0],rout1[31 downto 0]);

keyout[127 downto 96]<=w0^tem^rout1;
keyout[95 downto 64]<=w0^tem^rout1^w1;
keyout[63 downto 32]<=w0^tem^rout1^w1^w2;
keyout[31 downto 0]<=w0^tem^rout1^w1^w2^w3;

end Behavioral;
```

Error found is

> ERROR:HDLParsers:164 - "D:/Files/newpro/keygeneration.vhd" Line 52.
>   parse  error, unexpected INTEGER_LITERAL, expecting RETURN or
>   IDENTIFIER or  RSQBRACK.

I have shown the 52nd line in the code. I have got the same error for all the assignment statements from line 52. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: `t1: sbox port map(w3(23 downto 16),tem(31 downto 24)); -- WAS downto 0))` The constraint on the actual should match the formal (the lengths aren't the same).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 errors:

VHDL does not use `[]` for indexing arrays (though they are used for *signatures*). Use `()` for indexing arrays instead.

There is no `^` operator in VHDL. Use `xor` instead.

Comment: .thank you. it worked. but im getting an error during mapping.                          
Too many bonded comps of type "IOB" found to fit this device.
ERROR:Pack:18 - The design is too large for the given device and package. can you please help? im using virtex 4

Comment: @soulz This is a new question. Please ask it as such.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mean this:

```
w0<=key[127 downto 96];
```

you mean this:

```
w0<=key(127 downto 96);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22374865)

Comment: @DebanjanB How would you know? I teach VHDL; it doesn't seem to appear on your profile. It is exactly an answer: the user wrote `w0<=key[127 downto 96];` but should have written `w0<=key(127 downto 96);`

Comment: Irrespective of the VHDL factor, this answer landed in the VLQ queue. As a part of the review process we have suggested you to add the required verbatim so then answer is useful to the future readrers.

Comment: @DebanjanB _we have suggested you to add the required verbatim_ ? What should I add verbatim?